# Trouble copying a folder with a workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow, folder, sharepoint-designer

I'm using a "display" flag for people to only see what they care about, when display is set to  "no" i just copy the item to a different list and remove it from the original list. I am using a workflow to do this, my problem is that I just got asked to do this with a document library instead of a list. If they're just documents the behavior is fine, but if it is a folder there is no way of starting the workflow.

Anyone knows a workaround this? When I googled the problem, the first post was something that showed how to create custom workflow conditions. I'm looking (and hoping) for a quicker solution to this problem. (I need to be done with this by tomorrow) any input would help tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about SharePoint designer workflows then there is no way to hook this up to a 'folder change event'. Very annoying.

You will need to consider something else such as an event receiver.

Comment: Yeah, I did mean a SPD workflow... That really sucks. Would there be perhaps another approach to this? All I need to do is given an option to hide documents and folders. Moving them to a different list was the first thing I thought of, but perhaps there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: Perhaps you can create a view that carries out the filtering.